# Applying filter to queryset only when query is provided in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Let's say I have a model called `Article` with the field `title`. I have a method that returns a queryset for this model, and the method takes an optional argument called `query` which if provided, is used to filter out the queryset. So something like this:

```
def get_articles(query=None):
    if query:
        return Article.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
    else:
        return Article.objects.all()
```

This works fine, but notice how this method has two return statements, as in, I'm writing out two separate queries. Is there a way to do this in one go? In other words, the ideal scenario would be writing just one query instead of two. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Weird request, but try `Article.objects.filter(**({'title__icontains': query} if query else {}))`. Although I don't see any problem with your solution, (except that you can simply remove `else`) in fact I would say it is better than anything one may come up with to remove the extra return statement (the snippet in this comment included, it is _ugly_).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the number of `return` statements to one with:

```
def get_articles(query=None):
    qs = Article.objects.all()
    if query:
        qs = qs.filter(title__icontains=query)
    return qs
```